# SparkStreaming: How to get list like collect()

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming

I am beginner of SparkStreaming.
I want to load HBase record at SparkStreaming App.
So, I write the the under code by python.
My "`load_records`" function is getting HBase Records and return the records.
SparkStreaming can not use `collect(). sc.newAPIHadoopRDD()` need to be used at Driver Program. But SparkStreaming do not have the method which can get objects from workers to driver.
How to get HBase Record at SparkStreaming? or How to call `sc.newAPIHadoopRDD()`?

```
def load_records(sc, table, keys):
    host = 'localhost'
    keyConv = "org.apache.spark.examples.pythonconverters.ImmutableBytesWritableToStringConverter"
    valueConv = "org.apache.spark.examples.pythonconverters.HBaseResultToStringConverter"
    rdd_list = []
    for key in keys:
        if table == "user":
            conf = {"hbase.zookeeper.quorum": host, "hbase.mapreduce.inputtable": "user",
                "hbase.mapreduce.scan.columns": "u:uid",
                "hbase.mapreduce.scan.row.start": key, "hbase.mapreduce.scan.row.stop": key + "\x00"}

        rdd = sc.newAPIHadoopRDD("org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableInputFormat",
                             "org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.ImmutableBytesWritable",
                             "org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result",
                             keyConverter=keyConv, valueConverter=valueConv, conf=conf)
        rdd_list.append(rdd)
    first_rdd = rdd_list.pop(0)
    for rdd in rdd_list:
        first_rdd = first_rdd.union(rdd)
    return first_rdd

sc = SparkContext(appName="UserStreaming")
ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 3)
topics = ["json"]
broker_list = "localhost:9092"
inputs = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc, topics, {"metadata.broker.list": broker_list})
jsons = inputs.map(lambda input: json.loads(input[1]))
user_id_rdd = jsons.map(lambda json: json["user_id"])
# the under line is not working. Any another methods?
user_id_list = user_id_rdd.collect()
user_record_rdd = load_records(sc, 'user', user_id_list)
```

Comment: Why do you want to collect int the first place? And how does it connect to `load_records`?